# Selenium does not "listen" to "webdriver.chrome.driver" property

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

My coworker using MacOS sent me their Selenium project, containing this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources\\chromedriver");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Because I'm using Windows, I downloaded chromedriver.exe in the same folder and changed the previous lines to:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

However, the test doesn't launch the driver, then fails after some time and I'm getting this error message:

```
caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "blablabla\resources\chromedriver"
```

So this means the project is looking for `chromedriver` and not `chromedriver.exe`. How come? How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a C# setup but the way it works for me is that I specify the folder (full path) where the driver is located.

Config class, notice I have specified the location of the driver and not the .exe-file.

```
"selenium": {
   "screenShots": "C:\\ScreenShots",
   "chromeDriver": "C:\\webdrivers",
   "driverUrl": "https://www.google.se"
}
```

Driver init.

```
    Driver = new ChromeDriver(Conf.Selenium.ChromeDriver)
    {
        Url = Conf.Selenium.DriverUrl,
    };
    Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```